# Railsinstaller trying to use unmapped drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

After installation completes,
the "Rails Environment configuration" window pops up:

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
# Rails Environment Configuration.
Your git configuration is incomplete.
user.name and user.email are required for properly using git and services such
as GitHub ( http://github.com/ ).
Please enter your name, for example mine is: Wayne E. Seguin
```

After setting my name, following error occurs:

```
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

Should I really have H:/ mapped to be able to install Rails?

UPD: I looked into c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\setup_environment.bat and found it uses HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH, I had no such environment variables. I added those, still it didn't helped.

UPD2: Still, I could run rails after installation. Meanwhile, I installed it on my virtual Ubuntu.

UPD3: @Luis: thank you, that must be the reason. Although I have set environment variable HOMEDRIVE to correct one, still, if I run "set homedrive" in cmd, it gives out wrong value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `setup_environment.bat` look for those environment variables.

Please see this post at the RailsInstaller list:

https://groups.google.com/group/railsinstaller/browse_thread/thread/2337bfed4557f3f1

While the error is not the same, it might be associated to the same environment variables.